# Approximate $\sqrt{7}$ using binomial theorem

Tags: binomial-theorem

How does one deduce the approximation of $\sqrt{7}$ to be $\frac{10837}{4096}$ by taking $x = \frac{1}{64}$ in the expansion of $\sqrt{1-x}$?

How should you approach such a question? I assume the first step would be to expand $\sqrt{1-x}$ which can only be done through binomial theorem (afaik).

That gives $\sqrt{1-x} = 1 - \frac{1}{2}(x) - \frac{1}{8}(x^2)$ + ... and so on.

How do you continue? I can't seem to figure out how taking $x = \frac{1}{64}$ accomplishes anything.

Comment: Well, $$\sqrt7=\frac83\sqrt{1-\frac1{64}}=\frac83\left(1-\frac12\frac1{64}-\frac18\left(\frac1{64}\right)^2+\ldots\right)$$ hence $$\sqrt7\approx\frac{8\cdot(8\cdot(64)^2-4\cdot64-1)}{3\cdot8\cdot(64)^2}=\cdots$$

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but, how did you get $\sqrt7 = \frac{8}{3}\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{64}}$?

Comment: Did you try to simplify $$\frac83\sqrt{1-\frac1{64}}$$ by any chance? No? Well, you definitely should...

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Ah, you're right, it is a duplicate of that. My apologies.

Comment: @Sam you don’t have to apologize, all math here is a duplicate of well known results, no field medals were given here! Of course it is better to look for duplicate if you are simply looking for an answer but if you want discuss some detail more you are absolutely free to ask an answer.

Comment: @gimusi. They don't give Field medals here ? I am really disappointed to hear that. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You would deserve a special medal for you kindness, pleasantness and sense of humor! Cheers

Comment: @gimusi The friendliness in this stack exchange is refreshing. Thanks!

Comment: @Sam. You well noticed this key aspect of the site !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Use for example

$$\sqrt{7}=\sqrt{9\cdot \frac79}=3\sqrt{\frac79}=3\sqrt{1-\frac29}$$

or according to the other hint use that

$$\sqrt{1-\frac1{64}}=\sqrt{\frac{63}{64}}=\frac38\sqrt 7$$